React native quiting because of CMake and Ninja
I am trying to build an app using react native. Whenever I install React-native-navigation and all its dependencies, I keep getting some errors. This is the latest error I got due to my installation.
It works fine If I'm just starting the project, but breaks whenever I am trying to do some navigation.
C++ build system [build] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\\Users\\MarksmenX\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" 
^-C ^
"C:\\react_native_apps\\atlasv101\\atlas\\node_modules\\react-native-reanimated\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\e6b4c1t2\\arm64-v8a" ^reanimated from C:\react_native_apps\atlasv101\atlas\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android

I tried installing CMake, and Ninja. I have added those to my env variables. I have done all I know, still to no avail.
I expect this to run smoothly on my emulator, but it is not.
